# flutter web: static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) don't match

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I had a flutter project . I added web support to my project.Everything was good till i upgrade flutter sdk.I am using master sdk.

Now when i try to run my application i got this error:

```
$ flutter run -d chrome
Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:                   
! analyzer 0.39.16                                                      
Running "flutter pub get" in myapp_web2...            1,098ms
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
/home/alt/.pub-cache/git/persianDatePicker-b20d15502d6cae5c5bc9b4219789e16b15debb26/lib/widget/dialog.dart:725
:45: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
  final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true);     
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             
../../../../../Software/Linux/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:119:20: Context:
Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {                           
                   ^^                                                   
Syncing files to device Chrome...                                  36.0s
Failed to compile application.
```

This is flutter doctor:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-7.0.pre.58, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

I also run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` but i still got this error.

```
$ flutter devices
2 connected devices:

Web Server (web) • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
Chrome (web)     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 86.0.4240.111
```

Comment: According to the [Flutter Web set up page](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#set-up), it's recommended to use `beta` channel for Flutter web. The `master` channel isn't really recommended either - try the `stable` channel. It's inferred [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases).

Comment: I changed sdk to beta but i got this error https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S7QdN8z7qq/ @Apealed

Comment: I am getting this problem in flutter mobile after running `flutter upgrade`. I am on master channel.

Comment: I removed dependency_overrides: analyzer: x.x.x entirely and problem is gone

Answer (score 1):

Switch back to the stable version, that was the only way I was able to solve that `flutter channel stable` then run `flutter upgrade` then `flutter run`